# libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) not found by yum

Tags: python, azure, centos, shared-libraries, yum

So I'm trying to install Azure on CentOS with yum: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest).

But it keeps telling me it needs libpython2.7.so.1.0:

```
[root@minnow02 Desktop]# yum install azure-cli
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package azure-cli.x86_64 0:2.0.28-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: azure-cli-2.0.28-1.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: azure-cli-2.0.28-1.el7.x86_64 (azure-cli)
           Requires: libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But I have python 2.7:

> [root@minnow02 Desktop]# python -V

```
 Python 2.7.5
```

> [root@minnow02 Desktop]# find / -iname "*pyth*.so*"

```
/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
/usr/local/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
/usr/local/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so
/usr/local/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

What's going on?

Comment: CentOs 6 or centos 7?

Answer (score 0):

I have test it with Centos 6.8 and Centos 7.4, can't reproduce your error.

Please use this command to install Azure CLI:

```
# 1. Install a package with repository for your system:
# On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install python27

# 3. Start using software collections:
$ scl enable python27 bash

# 4. Import the Microsoft repository key.
$ sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

# 5. Create local azure-cli repository information.
$ sudo sh -c 'echo -e "[azure-cli]\nname=Azure CLI\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/azure-cli.repo'

# 6. Install with the yum install command.
$ sudo yum install azure-cli
```

Please try it.

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)